# TypeError: Module name, 'lit' does not resolve to a valid URL

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit

I am trying out WebComponents for the first time and I am trying to use lit for it. It keeps showing this error

My HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <payment-sdk></payment-sdk>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit';
```

I have tried removing the module attribute from the HTML but it still didn't work. it now gave the error

```
javascript es6 import "expects exactly one argument"
```

I am also considering using Babel to compile it, but i do not think it would work since i am still getting errors
I also added `"type": "module"` in my package,json file

Comment: import's in browser modules need to use an [absolute or relative path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#module-name), and include the `.js` in the import file name - so you'd use `import {LitElement, html, css} from './lit.js';` if that's where your `lit.js` file is - unless you're bundling (what you call *using Babel to compile it*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ESM for your dependency `lit`. When you use ESM in this way, you should provide an absolute paths for the imports.

So, instead of simply doing `import {} from "lit"`, you should the specify the absolute URL to it, like `import {} from "../../node_modules/lit.index.js"` (or what-ever is the right path)

If you don't have the ESM copy of `lit` with yourself, alternatively you can use ESM CDNs like `esm.sh`. To use them, add the below script tag as the first child of your head tag

```js
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "lit": "https://esm.sh/lit@3.1.1",
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here, we are telling browser to load `lit` from the URL that we have mapped it to

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried esm.sh and it worked. but i would have lots of imports by the time i am done lol